# htaccess 404 redirect problem

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting

Here is my htaccess contents below.  The 404 redirect is to redirect anyone to the index.htm page if they type in the wrong address or click a link that is broken or moved.  The Problem is I get this "No input file specified." when a link is broken or typed wrong, here is an example [www.cases.com/1234.htm](http://www.cases.com/1234.htm)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ 
RewriteRule .* products/noimage.jpg [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cases.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cases.com/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
# Rewrite Rule for blog.cases.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog.cases.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1

ErrorDocument 404 /index.htm

AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html .php
```